# How is frequency chosen?

Tags: power, digital-logic

I am not a specialist in electronics. I'm just a programmer. I ask this question just for fun.

My question: How the frequency for a design of a digital circuit is chosen?

Is the frequency chosen "before-hand" before doing actual design, "as the last choice" after the circuit is already designed, or "in-middle" adjusting it several times during design?

What if it turns out that different parts of a big circuit require different optimal frequencies? Isn't it a reason for redesign of some parts of the circuit?

Could you describe the stages of choosing frequency during design?

How it has happened that many of "Core" series CPUs had lesser frequency than Pentium-4 having indeed greater speed?

I've also heard that lesser frequency leads to lesser power consumption. But aren't Core CPU having lesser frequency having nevertheless not lesser number of logical gates changing their state per second? Isn't the number of gates changing their state not frequency the factor which defines power consumption?

Comment: Depends on the circuit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I.** Most of the time chip will use different frequencies for different part of the chip. Now days even most basic 0.5$ mikrocontrollers have fairly complicated clocking scheme (well at least deserving separate chapter in datasheet). So clock frequency will be chosen on block by block bases.

**II.** At whats stage of design frequency is chosen:

a) I would claim that most of the  time it is at the early stage. One would get requirements (example: have to decode HD Video). Based on that one would chose architecture taking into account power/technology/cost(area) tradeoffs. One of the output of the architecture decision is clock frequency.

b) But some times the early decision is sub-optimal/wrong. So modification are being made. However this can be costly as usually different parts of the chip are designed in parallel. Changing one clock may trigger re-design of other block (due to interface and clock source itself). I would say that for this reason this is avoided. Of course it is easier for some block to change clock frequency then for other so "your millage may vary".

c) At the last stage of place and route (this is one of the last stages before sending chip to factory) sometimes one can have troubles closing on timing/power budget (ie. making design work at targeted frequency/power) so decision is made to lower clock frequency. This is definitely avoided as this means not meeting some of the marketing specs. But some times it is wiser to be faster on the market then doing redesign which at this stage will be really costly and time consuming.

But there is more:

d) Some times clock frequency decision is made after fabrication (if certain provision in the design are made beforehand). Due to manufacturing variability some chips turn out better then other. Than one can perform binning - sort the chips based on what maximum frequency those can work reliably and sell those faster at premium. I would say this is mostly used by PC processor vendors.

e) Sometimes ready chips are under clocked in the final equipment to save power (popular in the uC) if required processing power is lower then maximum allowed from the chip.

f) In some modern design clock can be adjusted dynamically. Then clock is changed in the field based on the load in order to save power.

**III.** So how the frequency is chosen and why it is some times design working at lower clock will have bigger processing capability:

Oh boy there are so many variables so this is engineering discipline on itself. You have take into marketing requirements, technology, cost, EMI, power, supported standard, IO requirements  etc etc ...

But basically one can dumb down this to following - in order to achieve given performance one can have faster clock (do things in series one after another) or do things in parallel at lower clock at the cost of using more transistors. Due to some factors - mainly pipeline stall/memory latency it is sometimes better to use more transistor then faster clock.

Comment: As a contribution to mazurnification's 3rd point, here is a "90 minute" guide about modern microprocessors, and why there's more to speed than just Megahertz: http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ it explains things like pipelining and superscalar structure in a basic manner.

Answer (score 7):

In the embedded arena, often a specific frequency is chosen because of constraints with the peripherals of the microcontroller.  For example, a 1.8432 MHz crystal (or multiple of this frequency such as 18.432 MHz) might be used because this base frequency divided by 16 results in a 115,200 baud rate for a UART.  32768 Hz is often used for low-power microcontroller applications because it is easily divided down to 1 Hz for time-keeping.

[Here is a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator_frequencies) of various crystal frequencies and the reason they exist.  The ones listed "UART clock" are often picked for microcontrollers for the reason given earlier; the specific one chosen depends on the circuitry of the BRG (baud rate generator) and desired baud rate(s).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, power dissipated by a CMOS circuit is a sum of static power consumption (caused by leakage currents) and dynamic power consumption (consumed only when the transistors are changing the logic state). The latter is a function of the switching frequency.

Here's an excellent TI's application note which describes it in more details:
http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/scaa035b/scaa035b.pdf

Said that, it's usually the best idea to select lower clock frequency. However, sometimes it makes more sense to use higher clock frequency so e.g. interrupt handler can finish its task faster, and switch the CPU into power saving mode between interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above people make speed vs. power trade offs.

At the high performance end of the market it's more complex - in the Intel case there are competing issues - how fast can I make the silicon go? depends - to execute an instruction takes several clocks - As a (very) simple example I might be able to build a 4 clock/instruction pipeline that clocks at 1GHz and a 6 clock/instruction pipeline that clocks at 1.25GHz I'll still retire 1 instruction on every clock and the 6 clock/instruction pipe will be faster

In the real world though things like pipeline bubbles occur, the more pipeline stages you have the more clocks you waste when you have to refill the pipeline - the 4 clock pipe will fill faster than the 6 clock pipe and on average (over a large bunch of benchmarks) the 6 clock pipe might take 2 clocks to retire every instruction compared with the 1.5 clocks for the 4 pipe stage design - the 4 stage design will out perform the 6 stage one (1gHz/1.5 > 1.25GHz/2).

Of course it's hard for the marketing guys to sell things like this - people are so used to "more GHz means faster"

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration is EMC / EMI - electromagnetic compatibility / electromagnetic interference.

For example, high speed digital signals can create unintended RF (radio frequency - from long-wave to microwave) radiation that can be a source of interference for licensed RF usage. This includes broadcast AM (MW) radio, television broadcast, cellular phones, to GPS receivers and other electronic circuits.

In fact at high speeds, long (copper) traces on a printed circuit board (PCB) can act as antennas, for both transmitting and receiving. For example, a poorly laid out circuit could easily receive enough interference if a mobile phone is place too close to the circuit board to crash a system.

Satellites have to also consider ionizing radiation (i.e. gamma particles), one solution requires using radiation hardened ICs which may only operate at limited speeds due to the manufacturing process.

Because of this commercial products have to go through EMC / EMI testing before being allowed to be sold to the general market.